# Limit MongoClient to read only operations

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to connect to MongoDB in a read-only mode?

I'm currently using the driver for Node.js to create a new client with [`MongoClient.connect`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#connect):

```
require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect(url, {
    // options object
}, function(err, client) {
    // ...
});
```

I don't see anywhere in the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) how to create a client in read-only mode.

It is possible? how?

**Background:**
I'm building an app which connects to a MongoDB. Other developers in my team extend this app with plugins that consume data. A plugin is supplied with a `client` object to access the databse. I want to prevent other developers from accidentally making changes to the database.

Comment: You can assign a read role when adding a [new user](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/).

Comment: You can implement things like this using Mongo's security features - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/

Comment: Thank you both, it might be the solution. I would prefer, though, not having to deal with roles and users; and keep this in the driver level.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most clever workarounds for this scenario requires the usage of replica set. Simply connect only to one of the secondary node(s) will prevent write operation and achieve a read-only behaviour.